# Libreoffice using 25% total cpu, 100% one core

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, cpu, raspbian-buster

When Libreoffice is left open with a document in it, after a while Libreoffice begins using 25% of the total cpu usage. The usage doesn't stop, until:
 1. I close Libreoffice
 2. I press Ctrl+S even if it indicates the document was already saved.

Comment: If anything, this sounds like a bug in LibreOffice that should be reported to them. It's not clear how the Raspberry Pi is relevant to this question.

Comment: This is Pi-specific because I've never seen it happen on a non-Pi device.  And I am hoping someone on this community will know something about it and how to fix it.

Comment: This problem still happens to this day, so I finally gave up and have switched to using WPS Office. See: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=328484